# Geometry nodes: Checking if the surface of the face of a mesh is inside the other mesh

Tags: geometry-nodes

I wanted to delete the faces of the Target Mesh that are inside the Effector Mesh. Here is my simple attempt:

[image]

"Is Inside" node came from this [guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2spvhmmRsMs) (It uses Raycast node to select geometries inside the Target geometry)

However, the problem is Effector only deletes a face of the Target Mesh if the center of the face is inside.

[image]

As you can see, the Effector Mesh (the cube) is touching the surface of the face but it doesn't delete it, because the position attribute of a face domain is defined by the center (shown in red dot).

Normally, people would say "just add more geometry (faces)" but that's not an option here

Should there be some kind of interpolation to do here? How would you do it?

Comment: feels like you can use it for points instead of faces, so it will delete faces containing this specific vertex

Comment: Btw, why don't you just use boolean node instead?

Answer (score 1):

For large faces, you can check, if they intersect instead of checking, if they are within the other object.

If you have both, small and large faces, you may check for both and combine it with a logical *Or*.

Here is an example for checking for intersection. The node setup is bound to the cube.

[image: intersection nodes]

[image: no intersection]

[image: intersection detected.]